# How to redirect a link only when clicked on Android devices?

Tags: android, deep-linking

A website sends confirmation emails upon successful signup, and in that confirmation email is a confirmation link which takes the user back to the login page of the website. Now I am adding an Android app, but when Android users sign up on the app and receive the email and click the link, it opens a browser and opens the website login page. Is there a way to make it so the confirmation link will deeplink to the android app's login page ONLY when clicked from Android devices, but will correctly open to the website login page otherwise?

Comment: Did you check this (https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)?